# LVLH to ECI Conversion

Tags: orbital-mechanics, coordinates, satellite-constellation, frames, transform

I'd like to transform LVLH coordinates to ECI coordinates. I've been looking at academic papers and other answers on here and other websites and have only seen the transformation in the other direction, from ECI to LVLH. I haven't been able to find documentation for this transformation and was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a direct cosine matrix (also called a "rotation matrix") which converts from ECI to LVLH, then the transpose of that matrix will perform the opposite rotation: LVLH to ECI.